# Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 not registered on x86

Tags: asp.net, excel, iis-6, oledb

I have a web project that is getting the following error message when I try to read from an excel document: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

```
Dev Environment: IIS7, 64bit Windows
Deployment environment: IIS6, 32bit windows
```

I was able to fix the issue on my dev environment by setting the application pool to allow 32 bit applications.

IIS6 does not have that option though. All the resources online explain how to make it work on a 64bit windows but I can't find a solution for x86 and IIS6. I tried setting the target platform to x86 for all projects in my solution and that did not resolve the issue. ASP.NET v2 is in the IIS6 web service extensions and it is set to allowed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Waiting on network admin. I did notice though that office is not installed on the server so that probably has something to do with it.

Comment: jings, they take their time :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an obvious question, but did you check to see if the provider is installed on the server?

> [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c06b8369-60dd-4b64-a44b-84b371ede16d)

It'll appear as *Microsoft Access database engine 2010* in Add/Remove Programs.

Comment: Not sure. I assumed it was part of the default windows/office install. I sent your link to our server admin so we will see.

Comment: Did you ever get a response to this problem?  My Dev machine and Live server have the same specs as you mentioned:

Dev: Windows 7 64-bit IIS7
Live: Server 2003 32-bit IIS6

I'm getting the same problem on both Local and Live, despite having changed my App Pool setting in IIS and trying to change the Platform for my Web Project to x86 instead of Any CPU.